# Get the name of a std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

In the following toy-example, I would like to get the name of a function. The function itself was given as an `std::function` argument. Is it possible in C++ to get name of a `std::function` object?

```
void printName(std::function<void()> func){
    //Need a function name()
    std::cout << func.name();
}

void magic(){};

//somewhere in the code
printName(magic());

output: magic
```

Otherwise I would have to give the function's name as a second parameter.

Comment: Is this example complete? Couldnt you just use a preprocessor TOSTRING to convert the magic to string? printName(TOSTRING(magic))

Comment: It's not possible. Once compiled, you lose all information like that, C++ doesn't have any kind of [type introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection). The only possibility is compiler-dependent, using the debug information to try and find it out.

Comment: `std::function` doesn't need to encapsulate anything with a name...

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: `printName(magic());` won't compile.

Comment: If the following were solved we could use `.target` to solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706805/how-to-convert-a-function-pointer-to-function-name/

Comment: What is the name of a lambda expression?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No there isn't. Function names (like variable names) are compiled out so they are not visible at run-time.

Your best bet is to pass the name of the function (use a `std::string` or a `const char*`) as you've suggested yourself. (Alternatively you could base a solution on `__func__` which was introduced in C++11.)

Answer (score 13):

The answer is no, but you could make something like

```
template<class R, class... Args>
class NamedFunction
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::function<R(Args...)> func;
    NamedFunction(std::string pname, std::function<R(Args...)> pfunc) : name(pname), func(pfunc)
    {}
    R operator()(Args&&... a)
    {
       return func(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
    }
};
```

And then define a preprocessor

```
#define NAMED_FUNCTION(var, type, x) NamedFunction<type> var(#x,x)
...
NAMED_FUNCTION(f, void(), magic);
```

Answer (score 7):

Given a `std::function` it has a member function called `target_type` which returns the `typeid` of the stored function object.  That means you can do

```
void printName(std::function<void()> func){
    //Need a function name()
    std::cout << func.target_type().name();
}
```

This returns an implementation-defined string that is unique for each type.  With Visual Studio, this string is human-readable already.  With gcc (or maybe it's glibc?  I don't know who takes care of what in detail) you need to use `abi::__cxa_demangle` after including `<cxxabi.h>` to get a human-readable version of the type name.

**EDIT**
As Matthieu M. pointed out, given a function pointer, the type returned by this will just be the function's signature.  For example:

```
int function(){return 0;}
printName(function);
```

This will output (assuming you demangled if necessary) `int (*)()` which is not the function's name.

This method will work with classes though:

```
struct Function
{
    int operator()(){return 0;}
};

printName(Function{});
```

This will print `Function` as desired, but then doesn't work for function pointers.

Comment: and Visual Studio is actually MSVC :p

Comment: There is a big difference between the name of a function and its signature; on [gcc](http://ideone.com/Gp3oWQ) I get `PFvvE` as a display for `void magic()` because only the signature is encoded. Not sure about MSVC.

Answer (score 3):

You could also have your function with a string parameter for the name and then use a macro to call it

```
void _printName(std::function<void()> func, const std::string& funcName){
    std::cout << funcName;
}
#define printName(f) _printName(f, #f)

void magic(){};

//somewhere in the code
printName(magic);
```

See [example](http://cpp.sh/4s4f)

Answer (score 1):

Maintain your own map from function pointer to name.

```
template<class Sig>
std::map<Sig*, const char*>& name_map() {
  static std::map<Sig*, const char*> r;
  return r;
}

struct register_name_t {
  template<class Sig>
  register_name_t( Sig* sig, const char* name ) {
    name_map()[sig]=name;
  }
};
#define TO_STRING(A) #A
#define REGISTER_NAME(FUNC) \
   register_name_t FUNC ## _register_helper_() { \
     static register_name_t _{ FUNC, TO_STRING(FUNC) }; \
     return _; \
   } \
   static auto FUNC ## _registered_ = FUNC ## _register_helper_()
```

Simply do `REGISTER_NAME(magic);` to register the name `magic` to the function `magic`.  This should be done at file scope, either in a header or a cpp file.

Now we check if the `std::function` has a function pointer matching its signature stored inside of it.  If so, we look it up in our `name_map`, and return the name if we find it:

```
template<class Sig>
std::string get_function_name( std::function<Sig> const& f ) {
  auto* ptr = f.target<Sig*>();
  if (!ptr) return {};
  auto it = name_map().find(ptr);
  if (it == name_map().end()) return {};
  return it->second;
}
```

this is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score -4):

I think the simplest solution is to use `typeid(fun).name()` for example like this:

```
#include <typeinfo>

#include <stdio.h>

void foobar( void )
{
}

int main()
{
  printf( "%s\n", typeid( foobar ).name() );
  return 0;
}
```

Now, it have a lot of drawbacks, and I would not recommend using that.
First of all, IIRC it shows the symbol of the function, not the name you used in source code.
Also, the name will change from compiler to compiler.
And finally, RTTI is slow.

[edit]
Also, I'm not sure how it works with std::function. Never used that, honestly.

Comment: The name will be of the `std::function<...>` type, not of what the `std::function` *holds*.